# Add "custom" jar to Kafka that runs on Kafka Startup

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to run a custom jar on Kafka process startup. My custom jar adds service discovery features which are more detailed than the basic zookeeper service discovery that Kafka uses.

1. How can I make Kafka load my jar on Startup?
2. I want to listen to certain Events, such as connection state changes (something like "state changed to Init/Connecting/Reconnecting/Disconnected" etc). Is there a way to subscribe to those events?

I am thinking of a "plugin interface" that I can use to retrieve the aforementioned functionality. I could not find anything related. Adding the jar to Kafkas `/libs/` folder makes the jar get loaded to the classpath, but it is not executed.

Comment: If you want something actually executed, you need to patch the broker startup script to do so

Comment: @cricket_007 I was hoping that I could achieve this without changing the code of Kafka "manually".

Comment: My point is that I doubt there is some piece of the Kafka startup code that says "run all classes that match some  pattern" or "run method() of all implementations of an interface on the classpath". You're welcome to look over the Kafka source code. The server start main method is not doing anything complex like plugin loading https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/Kafka.scala

Comment: And you don't need to  change any code more than a shell script https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your input. I've stumbled upon both of the mentioned links before. Changing the main method looks like the most promising option for now. I don't get the grasp of changing the server startup script though? How would I be able to change the script and have it launch my class (within the Kafka process)? Launching it in a separate task is trivial, but does not let me "monitor" the Kafka process itself with ease. When launched within the Kafka process, my Service Discovery code will automatically detect process crashes as well as when the process gets a zombie process.

Comment: You need to catch a SIGHUP, TERM, or KILL signal at some layer, I agree. When I hear service discovery, my thoughts go to Consul agents, but I don't think that even provides such features as process termination. If you would like something like that, then perhaps you want a tool like supervisord or Circus